# Chunking a message into smaller chunks in C#

Tags: c#, message

I have a C# class to create a message.

```
    public class ExMessage
    {
        private UInt16 m_SendingId = 123;
        private byte m_control_byte_1;
        private enum destination_service : byte
        {
          serv_1 = 0x0,
          serv_2 = 0x1
        };
        private byte m_pd;
        private byte m_filler_bytes;
        private byte[] m_payload;

        public byte[] Payload
        {
            get
            {
                return m_payload;
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor.
        /// </summary>
        public ExMessage(byte[] payload)
        {
            m_pd = 0x0;
            m_control_byte_1 = 0xA5;
            m_payload = payload;
            m_filler_bytes = 0xF;

        }

        protected void WriteBody(Stream stream)
        {
            stream.WriteByte(m_control_byte_1); 
            stream.WriteByte(0x0); 

            stream.WriteWordLittleEndian(m_SendingId); 
            stream.WriteByte((byte)destination_service.serv_2); 

            stream.WriteByte((byte)m_pd); // payload details

            stream.WriteByte((byte)m_payload.Length); //write the payload length

            var count = 0;
            while (count < m_payload.Length)  //copy over the actual payload.
            {
                stream.WriteByte((byte)m_payload[count]);
                count++;
            }

            var len = 48 - (5 + m_payload.Length);
            count = 0;
            while (count < len) //copy over spare bytes 0x3
            {
                stream.WriteByte(m_filler_bytes);
                count++;
            }
        }

        public byte[] ToBytes()
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            WriteBody(stream);

            return stream.ToArray();
        }
```

I create the message as follows

```
 var Message = new ExMessage(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("HelloWorld"));
```

Now my usage scenario is as follows.

1) The protocol that I am using imposes a size restriction of 40 bytes on the payload. If the number of bytes in the payload that I am passing is greater than `40` bytes it should be split into two messages.

2) Is there a way for the constructor to return a list of `ExMessage` objects based on the size of the byte array that I pass into it.

3) If not, what is the best way to handle this scenario

Comment: A few comments, somewhat independent of the question:

 - Incrementally writing to a MemoryStream is inefficient if you don't know the size beforehand. This is because of resizing of the internal buffer. It seems here like you will know it. Given this, pre-size the stream to make sure it is long enough for the entire block, even if you write it incrementally.
 - Be careful of letting a single MemoryStream get too large. Check out docs on large objects in .net
 - Instead of writing from m_payload incrementally, write the entire block at once with a single Write() call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
var size = 4;
var messages =
    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("HelloWorld") //48 65 6C 6C 6F 57 6F 72 6C 64
        .Select((b, i) => new { b, i }) // Enumerable of byte and index
        .GroupBy(x => x.i / size, x => x.b) // group by index divide by block size
        .Select(x => new ExMessage(x.ToArray())); // create messages
```

That gives me:

[image: messages]

You would implement it like this:

```
public class ExMessage
{
    private const int __size = 4;
    public static ExMessage[] Create(byte[] payload)
    {
        return payload
            .Select((b, i) => new { b, i })
              .GroupBy(x => x.i / __size, x => x.b)
              .Select(x => new ExMessage(x.ToArray()))
              .ToArray();
    }
    /* rest of class */
}
```

You'd then call it like this:

```
var messages = ExMessage.Create(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("HelloWorld"));
```

Comment: What package does the above solution need. Does it need C# Reactive extensions? If so I would prefer to avoid it.

Comment: @liv2hak - No, it's just standard LINQ.

Comment: I couldn't quite understand the logic. Could please explain it to me a bit more

Comment: I need to pass in the `chunk number` to my constructor ExMessage()

Comment: @liv2hak - You don't have a chunk number in the constructor for `ExMessage`, but if you need to add it then it would look something like this: `.Select(x => new ExMessage(x.Key, x.ToArray()))`.

Comment: @liv2hak - I added a bit of explanation. Does that help?

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I understand it better now. is x.Key the chunk number? that doesn't seem to work. I have added that in the constructor.

Comment: @liv2hak - Yes, `x.Key` should be your chunk number, starting with `0` and incrementing by one for each chunk.

Comment: I want the `__size` to be dynamic based on whether chunk number is `0` or `> 0`. But inside `GroupBy` I can't use key. How can I do this?

Comment: @liv2hak - That would just be a case of getting the maths right. Something like `.GroupBy(x => x.i == 0 ? (x.i/ __size) : ((x.i - __size) / __size0 + 1 ), x => x.b)`

Comment: @liv2hak - You really shouldn't unaccept the answer if you've changed your requirements. If things change you should add a new question or just ask a question in the comments.

Comment: @liv2hak - Sorry, this is correct: `.GroupBy(x => x.i / __size0 == 0 ? 0 : ((x.i - __size0) / __size + 1 ), x => x.b)`.

Comment: You are assuming that `__size` is the size when chunk number (`x.Key`) is non-zero  and `__size0` is the size when chunk number (`x.Key`) is zero ?

Answer (score 1):

No.

I'd use a static function on ExMessage, something like this:

```
class ExMessage
{
   ...
   public static List<ExMessage> CreateMessages(byte[] payload)
   {
      List<byte[]> chunks = ... split payload into 40byte chunks...
      return chunks.Select(p => new ExMessage(p).ToList();     
   }
   ...
}
```